# How do I search the Windows 8 Store?

Tags: windows-8, windows-store

I can't seem to find any search box in the store. Does it exist? How can I access it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From [this question on Microsoft Answers](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-windows_store/how-do-i-search-the-windows-8-store/caf5b20e-f747-4a1d-9afc-63f339ff99cb):

> To [search] the Windows 8 Store, click the Store tile on the Start screen and then press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> or touch swipe from the right edge to open charms, then use the Search charm to search for apps.

To clarify for people using a mouse:

1. Open the Store
2. Move your cursor to the top or bottom right corner
3. Click the search icon
4. Type your search

Comment: You can just open it to its main page, and start typing, as well, just like on the Start screen. Doesn't work on every page of the store, though.