# How can I search for an app in the Windows Store?

Tags: windows-8, windows-store

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I search the Windows 8 Store?](https://superuser.com/questions/434776/how-do-i-search-the-windows-8-store)

It seems like it is only possible to browse through apps in the Windows Store. How do I find a known app without having to find it on the web, and using its URL to get to its Store page?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can hit `Windows logo + Q`, type in your search term and select the Store app.

You will see the the same UI as in @Louis' answer. The difference is that you can do it from any app.

Comment: I am pretty sure you can do what he did in any app as well.

Comment: Yes you can, I'm highlight another entry point and a keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 5):

In the Store app, bring up the Charms bar, and click the Search icon.

Type the name of the app you are looking for:
[image: Windows Store App Search Charm]

Look for the app in the search results:
[image: Windows Store App Search Results]

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options. The default option is `Charms menu > search` which got mentioned before in this post.

But the easier and better option is to simply start typing when in the store. It will automatically open the search bar without having to go through the hassle of opening the charm bar :).