# Searching for Apps in the Windows Store

Tags: windows-8, windows-store

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I search the Windows 8 Store?](https://superuser.com/questions/434776/how-do-i-search-the-windows-8-store)

How can I search for an app in the Windows Store?

Comment: Why is it that this question was downvoted 3 times and the duplicate was upvoted 16 times? They present the same amount of information...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple actually.

1. You go to the charms bar by going to the top right corner of the screen.
2. Click on search button. (First button)
3. Then scroll down for the Store app and click on it.
4. Type in what you want to search for and it will display the results.

Comment: That's for the machine, right? Does it search the Store as well? What if you're offline?

Comment: It's even simpler if Windows Store app is the active one: the search will be in that app.

Comment: @MamtaDalal Well if you're offline then the store can't get any results which will return no results.

Comment: @AlexeyIvanov Well this is assuming that the Store app isn't the active one.